# Change icon on softkeyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, soft-keyboard

I have an `EditText` with `android:imeOptions="actionDone"`. The soft keyboard that pops up shows a tick mark. I want to change it to the one in google contacts search `-->|` . How can i do this? Can it be set in xml?

Comment: post your code? what you tried?

Answer (score 1):

[`android:imeOptions`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:imeOptions) flags include

- `actionDone`
- `actionNext`

Comment: can u be more explicit . i have given android:imeOptions="actionDone"

Comment: @preetha Other options give you different icons.

Comment: yeah but i couldnt see any which gives -->|  as in contacts search . Not sure if its device keyboard specific